# Oracle plan difference with "in" and "between"

Tags: oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

Can you help me with this plan I don't understand.
I am running a very simple request:

```
SELECT *
FROM  BOOKING.BOOKING_GRID BG
WHERE BG.hotel=128 and day between 8600 and 8602;
```

and another version:

```
SELECT *
FROM  BOOKING.BOOKING_GRID BG
WHERE BG.hotel=128 and day in (8600,8601,8602);
```

I don't get why the "between" version is making use of BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 when the "in" version does not? The performance is very different! Is it because IOT index can not perform "range scan"?

Thank you for your help!

---

Table index are:

```
BOOKING BOOKING_GRIDPK  UNIQUE  VALID   IOT - TOP   N   NO      NO  HOTEL, DAY, BOOKINGSTATE    
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_UNIQ   UNIQUE  VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, DAY, BOOKING, VALIDITYSTART  
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKINGSTATUS, ISDAYUSE, DAY 
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_INDEX7 NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKING, VALIDITYSTART   
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_INDEX10    NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, ISDAYUSE, BOOKINGSTATUS, DAY
```

And this is what I get:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM  BOOKING.BOOKING_GRID BG
  3  WHERE BG.hotel=128 and day between 8600 and 8602;

3584 ligne(s) sÚlectionnÚe(s).


Plan d'exÚcution
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1060169596

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Id  | Operation         | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                     |  6504 |   508K|   845   (5)| 00:00:11 |

|*  1 |  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| BOOKING_GRIDPK      |  6504 |   508K|   845   (5)| 00:00:11 |

|*  2 |   INDEX SKIP SCAN | BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 |   464 |       |   480   (7)| 00:00:06 |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=128 AND "DAY">=8600 AND "DAY"<=8602)
   2 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=128 AND "DAY">=8600 AND "DAY"<=8602)
       filter("DAY">=8600 AND "DAY"<=8602)


Statistiques
----------------------------------------------------------
         58  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
       6961  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
     200030  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       3142  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        240  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       3584  rows processed




SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM  BOOKING.BOOKING_GRID BG
  3  WHERE BG.hotel=128 and day in(8600,8601,8602);

3584 ligne(s) sÚlectionnÚe(s).


Plan d'exÚcution
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1233826949

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Id  | Operation         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                |  1869 |   146K|   681   (0)| 00:00:09 |

|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR  |                |       |       |            |          |

|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| BOOKING_GRIDPK |  1869 |   146K|    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=128 AND ("DAY"=8600 OR "DAY"=8601 OR "DAY"=8602))


Statistiques
----------------------------------------------------------
         57  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
        687  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
     200192  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       3142  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        240  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       3584  rows processed
```

---

Added: 09/09/2013

Clustering factor details for each index:

```
Table       Index            Cluster. factor     Table NRows
BOOKING_GRID    BOOKING_GRID_INDEX7  276 816 902     313 290 258   
BOOKING_GRID    BOOKING_GRID_UNIQ    131 055 933     313 290 258   
BOOKING_GRID    BOOKING_GRID_INDEX10     121 702 397     313 290 258   
BOOKING_GRID    BOOKING_GRIDPK       108 115 708     313 290 258   
BOOKING_GRID    BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5   24 238 404     313 290 258
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this: IN deals with a discrete list (here, just 3 values) where BETWEEN has to consider continuous ranges. (Check the expected rows returned: 1869 for the IN example, 6504 for BETWEEN.)

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't INDEX RANGE SCAN (in IN-request plan) considering a range of continuous values? I don't get why there should be any difference.
Also can the double index used in the BETWEEN-request plan be related to a problem of wrong PHYSICAL GUESSES?

Comment: @RenaudBlue - no, an INDEX RANGE SCAN is considering a range of index entries which can be totally discontinuous like 3, 4, 5, 17, 109, etc. (Remember, it only stores the values that are in the table.) Think "continuous" as in math - there are an infinite number of real numbers between 8600 and 8602, not 3.

Comment: yes I see the difference between enumerated values and continuous range values. But in this context, days are discrete integers and there is index on it. So I wish I could optimize there...
My question behind the first one is we are in Index Organized Table so why would I use BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 with SKIP SCAN when I could just use the main IOT index BOOKING_GRID_PK!

Comment: @RenaudBlue - sorry, I can't find anything definitive about the IN vs BETWEEN with respect to the optimizer, but in my tests, the BETWEEN always estimated a higher # of rows returned (I was testing using a NUMBER(10)). As for the SKIP SCAN, I agree that it's strange that it didn't pick the PK index; maybe try a hint to see if you can force it. If that helps, it might be worth checking the stats on the table/indexes.

Comment: I'have added information about table n rows and clustering factors. I am very suprised to see such a big clustering factor for the main index of the IOTable. And also to see that a secondary index can have a lower clustering factor than the main index. What do you think?

Comment: Those clustering factors do look pretty odd for an index organised table. What is the meaning of BOOKINGSTATE, and how many unique values does it have?

Comment: To quote the documentation "a high clustering factor means that it costs more to use a range scan to fetch rows by rowid" and since the clustering factor on the PK index is a fair bit higher than INDEX5, it looks like that's the issue with it choosing the SKIP SCAN execution plan.